# IOS ChatSDK - Failed to observe account status updates

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

Im trying to observe the agent status every time I change it from the zendesk Dashboard, but its not working for me. Im just able to get it once for the first time that Im launching the view .

How can I make it reactive and get the updates of the status please.

I used this function :

```
    Chat.accountProvider?.observeAccount { (account) in
    
    switch account.accountStatus {
    
       case .online :
         print("agent is online") 
       case .offline :
         print("agent is offline")
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed now.
I just called  `Chat.connectionProvider?.connect()` in  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function of `AppDelegate.swift` file.